# I am getting runtime error upon incrementing the pointer, what is the plausible reason?

Tags: c++11, pointers, runtime, runtime-error

I am new to C++, while I was implementing a tag class, I encountered a runtime error.
Upon debugging I found out that the runtime error was caused by incrementing pointer(**) attrib_list, but the other pointer which points to same memory address produces no error on incrementing, 
Please explain to me what is the reason for this odd behaviour ?
I used hackerrank online ide to compile this code

```
class Tag{
public:
    Tag():
       tagname{""}, sz{0}, t_sz{0}, attrib_list{nullptr}, ptr_nav{nullptr}{
    }

    Tag(string name, int n_att):
        tagname{name}, sz{0}, t_sz{n_att}, attrib_list{new string*[n_att]}{
            for(int i=0; i<n_att; i++){
                attrib_list[i] = new string[2];
            }
            ptr_nav = &attrib_list[0];      //take risk here
    }

    ~Tag(){
        for(int i=0; i< t_sz; i++){
                delete[] attrib_list[i];
            }
        attrib_list = nullptr;
        ptr_nav = nullptr;
        t_sz, sz = 0;
    }


    // this function produces rintime error
    void add_attribute(string name, string value){
        (*attrib_list)[0] = name;
        (*attrib_list)[1] = value; 
        sz++;
        attrib_list++;
    }


  /*
     This does not produce any error, why ????
     void add_attribute(string name, string value){
        (*ptr_nav)[0] = name;
        (*ptr_nav)[1] = value; 
        sz++;
        ptr_nav++;
    }
   */

private:
    string tagname;
    string **attrib_list, **ptr_nav;
    int sz, t_sz;
};

int main() {
    Tag t("tag1", 2);
    t.add_attribute("value1", "1");  //runtime error
    t.add_attribute("value2", "2");  //runtime error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are not trying to learn about pointers, I would strongly suggest you to use `vector` and `unique_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

After two calls to `add_attribute`, `attrib_list` is incremented twice and now points past the end of the original `new[]`-allocated array. Which is not in itself a problem.

But then your `Tag` instance goes out of scope, its destructor runs and tries to access `attrib_list[i]` on a now-invalid `attrib_list` pointer, which of course exhibits undefined behavior.

---

Unrelated to the immediate issue: `t_sz, sz = 0;` does not assign 0 to two variables (as you seem to believe), but only to `sz`. Read about comma operator in your favorite C++ reference. In any case, you don't need to do that in the first place (nor to set the two pointers to `nullptr`) - they are about to be destroyed anyway, their values at that point don't matter.